# In SQL query (BigQuery) How get all rows where CreatedDatetime is Today in Moscow tz from column with UTC tz?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with CreatedDatetime column. This column is in UTC timezone (Values look like this:
2020-12-20 01:00:00 UTC). I need to get all rows where date is Today, but in Europe/Moscow timezone, which is +3 hours. Instead

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(CreatedDatetime, HOUR), INTERVAL 3 HOUR) AS date_hour_msk
FROM table_name
WHERE DATE(CreatedDatetime) = CURRENT_DATE('Etc/GMT')
```

I need something like this:

```
WHERE CreatedDatetime >= 'yesterday 21:00:00' AND Created <= 'today 21:00:00'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bigquery, you can convert an UTC timestamp to a local timezone like this:

```
TIMESTAMP(CreatedDatetime, 'Europe/Moscow')
```

Presumably, you want something like:

```
select TIMESTAMP(CreatedDatetime, 'Europe/Moscow') as local_time
from table_name
where DATE(CreatedDatetime, 'Europe/Moscow') = CURRENT_DATE('Europe/Moscow')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this

```sql
WHERE DATE(CreatedDatetime, "+03:00") = CURRENT_DATE("+03:00")
```